# Is it possible to determine the type of object on-line in one-pass, including macros?

Tags: c, parsing

I have a very simple parser that provides a small section of the C language; it looks at a well-formed translation unit and, with one pass and online, determine what the global symbols and types (function, struct, union, variable,) if one is not trying to trick it. However, I'm having trouble determining if it's a `struct` or a function in this example,

```
#define CAT_(x, y) x ## y
#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(x, y)
#define F_(thing) CAT(foo, thing)

static struct F_(widget) { int i; }

F_(widget);

static struct F_(widget) a(void) { int i;
    return i = 42, F_(widget).i = i, F_(widget); }

int main(void) {
    a();
    return 0;
}
```

It assumes that the parenthesis is a function and parses this this way,

```
[ID<stati>, ID<struc>, ID<F_>, LPAR<(>, ID<widge>, RPAR<)>, LBRA<{>, RBRA<}>].
[ID<F_>, LPAR<(>, ID<widge>, RPAR<)>, SEMI<;>].
[ID<stati>, ID<struc>, ID<F_>, LPAR<(>, ID<widge>, RPAR<)>, ID<a>, LPAR<(>, ID<void>, RPAR<)>, LBRA<{>, RBRA<}>].
[ID<int>, ID<main>, LPAR<(>, ID<void>, RPAR<)>, LBRA<{>, RBRA<}>].
```

When in fact, what it thinks is the function at the top is actually a `struct` declaration and the top two should be concatenated. What is the simplest way to recognise that this?

- Two-pass, emulating what actually happens in macro replacement; I would have to build a subset of the C pre-processor;
- like [the C lexer hack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_lexer_hack), except with macros;
- backtrack with the semicolon at the end; that seems hard;
- somehow recognise the difference at the beginning, (probably requiring me to add `struct` to my symbol table.)

Comment: Have you considered using libclang?

Comment: Or looked at the sources for [cflow](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/cflow/cflow-1.5.tar.xz) or [cproto](https://invisible-mirror.net/archives/cproto/cproto.tar.gz) -- note `cproto.tar.gz` is *double* gzipped (twice), I have no idea why. Both do similar things to what you are attempting and may save reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I don't think you will easily implement the rescan behavior of macro expansion in a one-pass manner.  But perhaps you could push the preprocessing support down a level, between parser and lexer, so as to make the parser one-pass in terms of tokens (as opposed to preprocessing tokens).  This would reflect aspects of the C translation model.

Comment: You cannot handle this without doing macro replacement unless you considerably want to limit what macro definitions are allowed. In this example, macro replacement resulted in a structure tag, but it could have produced a full structure definition or more. To parse what the macro replacement produces, you must do the macro replacement.

Comment: In general, I suspect macros are totally beyond the scope of my very simple programme; I only want to do very simple macros that result in keywords.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, if you want to be able to handle preprocessor macros, you will need to implement (or borrow) a preprocessor.

Writing a preprocessor mostly involves coming to terms with the formal description in the C standard, but it is not otherwise particularly challenging. It can be done online with the resulting token stream fed into a parser, so it doesn't really require a second pass.

(This depends on how you define a "pass" I suppose, but in my usage a one-pass parser reads the input only once without creating and rereading a temporary file. And that is definitely doable.)

Comment: I downloaded `mcpp`, whose `src` is more then 10x my `src`; I hesitate to implement a real pre-processor for this task. However, probably I could fake it in very much less; I'm only interested in macros that result in identifiers.

Comment: @neil: generally the appropriate measure for a software package isn't lines of code or megabytes of binary, but rather how much time it will take to integrate into your project. However, if you want to write a preprocessor, what will simplify your work is not having to deal with pp directives other than #define, assuming that's the case.